# service not stopping even after closing the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a modal window in which there is a directive in which I am calling a service which is making http requests inside a $interval after every 30 seconds, but when I close the modal window, the service is still running after every 30 seconds, is there a way in which I can stop it simultaneously while closing the modal window?

Comment: Can you post some code? it is hard to answer without any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular wrapped `interval` should be destroyed explicitly, as stated in the docs:

> Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed when you are finished with them. In particular they are not automatically destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's element are destroyed.

You should cancel the interval when the directive is removed, like this:

```
var stop = $interval(myFunc, 1000)

$scope.on('$destroy', () => {
    $interval.cancel(stop);
});
```